# Прокрутка контента мышкой

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть строка в которой контент очень длинный по ширине. Нужно что-то придумать чтоб передвигать его мышкой. Полосу прокрутку включить не подходит. Можно на jquery какие-то варианты. Спасибо.

https://jsfiddle.net/x2pnc5aq/24/

```
.row-items {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  background: green;
}

.item:nth-child(even) {
   background: blue;
}
```

Comment: А каруселью не подойдет? С кнопками вправо, влево?

Comment: нет, нужно именно двигать (drag) и без лишних плагинов

Comment: ну например http://jsfiddle.net/basarat/f7nNf/1/